# SVG scaling in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, scale

I've tried the solutions in the following questions but none of them seem to work:

- [Scaling/Resizing SVG in an HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739226/scaling-resizing-svg-in-an-html?rq=1)
- [How to scale SVG properly and responsively in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23666701/how-to-scale-svg-properly-and-responsively-in-html5?rq=1)
- [Best practice for using SVGs, regarding height and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352761/best-practice-for-using-svgs-regarding-height-and-width?rq=1)

In the last question, the height and width are both specified in the CSS, however I only want to specify one of the dimensions. For instance, currently I have a `max-height` in my CSS that controls the height of the image.

Here is the code I have:

### HTML

```
<a href='#schedule'>
    <img src='images/calendar.svg' alt='' role='presentation' class='nav-item-icon'>
    <span class='nav-item-text'>Schedule</span>
</a>
```

### CSS

```
.navigation-main a {
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.nav-item-icon {
    max-height: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-item-text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}
```

### SVG

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
    width="82.7272727273px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 91.59 110.063"
    enable-background="new 0 0 91.59 110.063" xml:space="preserve">
    <!-- codes -->
</svg>
```

### Results

#### Internet Explorer 11

[image]

#### Firefox and Chrome

[image]

I have tried removing the height and width attributes of the SVG but this makes the SVG 100% width of the parent element in all browsers unless I specify a width in CSS. Inlining the SVG does not make a difference.

There's probably a way to do this in JavaScript by getting the computed height and setting the width manually but I would prefer not to resort to such hacks. Is there a way to get the image to scale properly in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score -1):

In Internet-Explorer, you need to define viewBox so it scales well.
You have defined a viewBox, with a different width and height than your width and height attributes. 
Is this correct ? My guess is not.

Then you have also defined pixels with a comma value. 
This is nonsense. 
A pixel is a discrete unit. 
There is no half-pixel or quarter-pixel. 
IE probably doesn't properly sanitize or interprete those values.

You should probably try:

```
width="82px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 82 100"
```

Also get rid of `xml:space="preserve"`. 
IE doesn't support it.